# Edge browser window size growth

Tags: windows, window, microsoft-edge

The [internet](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/all/edge-does-not-remember-the-restored-size-and/d629ac04-0e89-4684-a1ef-17f3c766e041) is [littered](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/edge-doesnt-remember-window-size/71390b65-1ecf-49e8-ae7c-4fcb91ecf289) with [complaints](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/all/changing-edge-default-window-size/cb874ac4-8367-495a-ad75-7db3cf4075b0) that [the](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/all/microsoft-edge-window-size-and-position/36aa9d33-43f3-4c14-a46d-bdd120a108d4) Microsoft Edge browser doesn't remember window size (and position).  No meaningful solutions have been provided that don't require invoking 3rd party software to manage window dimensions.  But, I've noticed some more specific behavior that seems peculiar.  Note the red bars in the following image:
[image]
Starting with no Edge browsers, then opening a first one:  If I open a new browser via Ctrl+N, or if I first move my browser window some, then open a new window via Ctrl+N or via the Start menu, then the new window will be exactly 32 pixels taller than the last one.  The width is unchanged.  32 pixels is notable because that's the height of the top bar, and is also how far offset a new window is when opened via Ctrl+N.

The screenshot was generated by repeatedly opening windows with Ctrl+N.  There are a few variants on this behavior (in terms of window sizes staying the same or not), depending on how one repeatedly opens new windows, but I've only seen the size either (A) stay the same, or (B) height increase by 32 pixels.  I've verified this behavior on two different computers (different hardware and such).  And, my general observation has been that height changes a lot more than other aspects.  I've played around with a few thing and have not yet seen the width change.  Is there a chance that this long-standing bug boils down to something so predictable?  I ask because I'd considered reporting to Microsoft, but doubted the issue could have such an obvious source that they didn't already know about.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: "Is there a chance that this long-standing bug boils down to something so predictable?" - Maybe?  Sadly, with EdgeHTML being retired in favor of Chromium Edge, the bug will likely never be fixed.

Comment: It is not a bug, it is how Edge and indeed Microsoft Office applications work. Each new occurrence in the same session will offset by approximately the amount you showed. Long standing Microsoft Application behaviour

Comment: @John, look more closely.  The windows are offset by 32 pixels (as usual), but the vertical length of the window is also 32 pixels longer.  That's why there are two 32-pixel bars at the bottom of each window in the screenshot.

Comment: It is just the way Microsoft applications work. All the Office apps and Edge (and IIRC IE) work this way. Normal for Microsoft

Comment: @John, I've not observed this behavior before.  I just tested Excel and Word, and neither of them showed a window growing, only offsetting as is the norm.

Comment: The window size stays the same.  For production Edge, it does not grow but does offset.  Beta Edge may be subject to errors but production Edge is fine. Wait until the Beta product has been corrected

Comment: @John - production version certainly does grow in height for me while the beta doesn't.

Comment: Not for me on any production machine- my own or clients. I am not sure about your machines

Comment: @John - I tested it on an up to date Windows 10 Pro version 1903 (build 18362.476) and then installed the 1909 enabler patch (making the build number reported by winver to be1836**3**.476).  Results were the same.  In both (as 1903 and 1909 are the same) Edge is `44.18362.449.0` and `EdgeHTML 18.18363`.  The beta version I tested was version `Version 79.0.309.18 ` downloaded today.

Comment: Your results are different from mine in nearly 5 years of using Windows 10 and Edge. Strange

Comment: What's the question here? If this behavior has something to do with the window positioning bug? If so, that's not a question we can answer here.

Comment: I just tried it here and size is precisely equal. So it may be machine dependent, but as I noted, I have not seen such behavior in nearly 5 years and just tried it again here. Perfect results. Production Edge

Comment: @John I'm not surprised.  I've seen it on 3 (very) different machines, but not on a fourth.  Haven't yet been able to identify a common theme...

Comment: It is likely a machine / video issue. That is all I can surmise in this situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of the new Edge beta has changed.

This is the current Edge (1903 version) starting as small as possible in top right.  Notice that as you observed each opening (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>) increases the height but not the width.  When it hits the bottom of the screen it then bounces back up.  Before build 10586 it carried on to another monitor but doesn't any more.  Still seems buggy to me.

[image: Edge]

This is [Edge beta](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download).  Notice it doesn't change the height on opening new instances and doesn't bounce from the bottom of the screen but rather opens new windows to the right when it hits the bottom of the screen.

[image: Edge beta]

This is not confined to Edge but neither is it consistent.  Word for example jumps back up to top left and starts again rather than bouncing up or continuing to the right.

[image: Word]

None are really better or worse in my opinion - you have to put the new Window *somewhere* if you aren't to open it bang on top of the existing one and who opens 50 instances anyway.

The complaints in your question are not really related to this behavior though although you could be right about it being the cause.  Your links rather complain about windows not opening where you left them and that was fixed a long time ago for Edge (in 1607 [apparently](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/7566-remember-window-position-post760628.html#post760628)).  Certainly it hasn't happened to me for years.

Comment: Interesting about the beta version not doing this.  I updated the linked pages in my question to only include posts after 2016 to avoid the old bug you mentioned.

Comment: I think @ramhound is probably right in his comment on your question - as it is fixed in Chromium beta they probably won't bother fixing it.  Not much value in patching legacy versions as it isn't where the development is going.

Comment: I'd considered updating my question to ask if this merited documenting with the Microsoft team, but hadn't for that exact reason...I think I'll make the update and mark your answer so that this is resolved.

Comment: FYI: Edge Beta is Chromium not EdgeHTML.  I would not reduce the scope to just the Microsoft Team (you would not receive an answer from them)